# Finding the number of coins won by T

Tags: logic

Six persons P, Q, R, S, T and U play in a tournament called "High Rollers". Every game involved two players. Each of the participants played with every other participant exactly once. In the game both the players rolled an unbiased die each. The player who gets the larger number on the top surface of the die wins the game. Every game resulted in a win/loss. The player who wins, gets as many coins as the number on his die. The total number of games won by each person is distinct.
Further it is known that:

1. Q won his game against P.
2. The number of coins won by R was more than any one else.
3. U lost only two games, one against S and the other against R.
4. T wins at least two games.

R won 11 coins and he lost one game. If the total number of coins won by all the six players in the tournament was 47, then what was the number of coins won by T?

What I did till now:

Number of games won by P is 0
Number of games wom by Q is 1
Number of games won by R is 4
Number of games won by S is 5
Number of games won by T is 2
Number of games won by U is 3

How to find the number of coins?

Comment: How did you get to where you are now?  Can you explain your reasoning? E.g. why did $P$ not win any games?

Comment: You should present your problem in a better way. For example "R won 11 coins and he lost one game" is important as 1 to 4 but its hidden somewhere in the text. One should be able to referrence all relevant statement sby a number. Also you should present us your reasoning how you get the number of games that a person won.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't know how many games each of the people won, except for $R$ and $U$ (and, eventually $T$)

Now, if $R$ won $11$ coins by winning 4 matches, then the person who won 5 matches must have won by rolling a $2$ each time (you can't win by rolling a $1$, and if any of the winning rolls was higher than a $2$, this person would have won at least $11$ coins as well).

OK, so we know:

person with 5 wins won 10 coins

person with 4 ($R$) wins won 11 coins

person with 3 ($U$) wins won ? coins

person with 2 wins won ? coins

person with 1 wins won ? coins

person with 0 wins won 0 coins

Now, this should add up to $47$, but note that the person who won $1$ game can at most have won $6$ coins, and the other two can at most have won $10$ coins, so in order for the total to be $47$, they must have won in fact exactly that amount. So:

person with 5 wins won 10 coins

person with 4 ($R$) wins won 11 coins

person with 3 ($U$) wins won 10 coins

person with 2 wins won 10 coins

person with 1 wins won 6 coins

person with 0 wins won 0 coins

Finally, since $U$ only lost against $R$ and $S$, $U$ must have won against $T$, so $T$ did not win $5$ matches, but won at least $2$ matches, so $T$ won exactly two matches, and so must have won $10$ coins.

But again, we don;t know how many matches the other people won .. $P$ did not win all $5$ matches, and $Q$ won at least 1 match, but other than that we don't know. Still, we can answer the question just fine.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $R$ won the most amount of coins, which is $11$. However $S$ won $5$ games. Since the lowest possible amount of coins that can be earned per win is $2$, we know that $S$ won $10$ coins. Thus there are $47-11-10=26$ coins unaccounted for among the $1$ win by $Q$, the $2$ wins by $T$, and the $3$ wins by $U$. The most amount of coins that $Q$ can win in his only win is $6$ coins. That means that $T$ and $U$ must win at least $20$ coins. However, neither can win more than $10$ coins because $R$ won the most amount of coins. Thus they must have each won $10$ coins. Therefore $T$ won $10$ coins.

Comment: How do you know lowest possible amount of coins per person is 2? @JohnGriffin

Comment: I know that the lowest possible of coins per win is $2$. Since dice only have values $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and it is impossible to win by rolling a $1$, it must be that the winner receives at least $2$ coins.

Comment: Why T or U can't win coins more than 10? @JohnGriffin

Comment: @anglena Because we are told that $R$ won $11$ coins and that he won more coins than anyone else.